# What's the function of the letter h?

Tags: etimología

What's the function of the letter *h* in Spanish? Even though it's not pronounced there must be a reason of its existence.

I mean the case when the letter *h* it's not accompanied by the *c* (**ch**).

Comment: Related: [Latin /f/ to Spanish /h/](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/680/latin-f-to-spanish-h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The silent, leading *h* exists for etymological reasons.  As Vulgar Latin developed into Castilian, many (but not all) *f*s at the beginnings of words began to be pronounced as, and spelled with, *h*.  Eventually, the sound represented by *h* was lost, but it remained in the spelling of words.

There are many examples of words in Spanish that start with *h* whose cognates in other languages start with *f*.  For example, with English we have the pair *halcón* and *falcon*; with Latin, *hacer* and *facere*; with French, *hierro* and *fer*; with Portuguese, *hablar* and *falar*.

Also interesting: the names Hernán and Fernando are cognate (if two words in the same language can be thus described).  Indeed, some contemporary sources refer to a chap named Fernando Cortés.

Comment: Was *h* ever used to represent a glottal stop?  I ask because it apparently is used to represent a glottal stop in Seri, a random indigenous language in Mexico: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop

Comment: @Andy interesting question. Not as far as I'm aware. And if wikipedia is to believed, Seri's writing system was developed in the middle of last century by an American linguist/missionary couple. It wasn't created in an attempt to adapt an unrelated language's alphabet to Seri (with all sorts of assumptions that simply do not hold (which is basically what happened with other indigenous languages in what is today Mexico)).

Comment: ah fair enough, I mistakenly assumed that Seri orthography was related to Spanish without reading further into it.

Answer (score 7):

In the Middle Age, the letter `u` represented both the *u* and the *v* sounds. But then the diphthong *ue* was created to replace the letter *o* in some cases, and words like `ovo` were rendered into `uevo`.

This word could be read as *uevo* or *vevo*, so to mark that the initial *u* should be readed as *u* and not as *v*, it was prefixed with the `h`, and thus words like *huevo*, *hueso* and so on were created.

It is worth noting that some related words still have the original *o*, like *óseo* (from *hueso*), or *ovíparo* (from *huevo*).

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta! Bienvenido a [spanish.se]

Answer (score 3):

'H' keeps because of etymology of words, or the diphthongization of the vowel or when it receives the accent.

In times is pronounced, ie: *chacha* is not the same as caca

Comment: Note that until the last decade, "h" was not considered a letter of the Spanish alphabet in such cases because "ch" was a letter.

Comment: Another example: "has" (verb haber) is not the same than "as" (ace)

Answer (score 1):

`H` does have a sound when forms part of the digraph `ch`, for example:

1. Chicharrón
2. Muchacho/a
3. Chantaje

Wikipedia lists one exception to the above rule: Hámster (which comes from the German). More examples are: `Hall` (pronounced `Jol` in Spanish), `Hardware`, `Hobby`, etc.

On these cases `H` is pronounced as you would pronounce an `H` in English or a `J` in Spanish.

Here's an excerpt from Wikipedia:

> Se corresponde con la letra H del alfabeto romano, procedente de la
>   eta griega, que proviene de la het fenicia. Su nombre en español,
>   hache, viene probablemente del latín rústico *haca, a través del
>   francés hache.

Comment: Note that English `H` and Spanish `J` are not pronounced the same at all, though if you are a native speaker of one and a beginner in the other you'll be understood by pronouncing them the same until you learn the other sound. `H` is [`[h]`, the voiceless glottal fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative). `J` is [`[x]`, the voiceless velar fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative).