# What is the difference between Spanish and Ladino?

Tags: dialectos, comparación-de-idiomas

What are the main differences between Spanish and Ladino?

I thought I would be able to hear the difference in Ladino podcasts, but I don't. Both languages sound the same.

Comment: I am always questioning linguistic patterns and choices.I live in Eilat Israel
where I am called upon constantly to use and enjoy my linguistic skills!
Today---at a small local bus stop, a man about 60 asked me in Hebrew if I was from Argentina.He heard me speaking Spanish to a friend,I replied "yes".He offered that being from Turkey he spoke Spanish.
I said,"No,you spoke Ladino.I was there in Turkey in a big synagogue,I heard Ladino.He smiled.
Ladino sounds a bit choppy to me---but fun to decipher!

Answer (score 9):

Spanish is the old Castilian language, a Romance one, related to Portuguese, Galician and Catalan, with influences from Arabic and French, and **which has evolved naturally since**, spoken nowadays in Spain, Hispanic America (including South of USA), Equatorial Guinea and Philippines.

Ladino is the same old Castilian language, also romance, also related to Portuguese, Galician and Catalan, with the same influences from Arabic but less influence from French, **which has not evolved since Ferdinand and Isabella expelled jews from Spain in 1492**, spoken nowadays by sephardi jews (they called Spain as Sefarad, hence the name they give to theirselves).

So yes, the answer from Jaime Cruz Triana is correct in that Ladino is ancient Spanish, and the historic reason is that Jews expelled in 1492 retained their language.

Comment: It has evolved somehow, Ladino spoken in Turkey/Middle East has adopted many words from Turkish.

Comment: @JoulSauron True. I referred to the same evolution as Spanish

Comment: I think you mixed the year's digits. It's 1492, not 1942 ;)

Comment: @itziki true. Corrected.

Comment: I keep hearing about Ladino and that it's a language spoken in Israel and the middle east, but I haven't found a modern sample of nowadays written Ladino/Sephardic Spanish, like a newspaper or a wikipedia article (like, for instance, those available in Chabacano). Furthermore I hear that Ladino is being displaced by Argentinean Spanish in Israel and that there are virtually no Ladino speakers any longer. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: deStrangis: As a resident of Israel I can tell you that some people in Israel do speak Ladino (my uneducated guess is an order of magnitude of 50,000 speakers, almost all of them also speak Hebrew), yet - and like other jewish dialects such as Yiddish - one can not compare its contemporary status to the situation before the Holocaust, when it was spoken by a large fraction of the non-ashkenazi jews and was used in everyday-life. Most of the current speakers are elderly people who were born in Ladino-speaking communities such as the Balcan or Turkey and later immigrated to Israel, and it is ver

Comment: You said: "-and like other jewish dialects such as Yiddish-" but that is plain wrong. Ladino is not a 'jewish dialect'. It is an independent language, related to spanish, and happens to be speaked by a certain branch of jews. And you seem to forget the special status given to Ladino by Spanish Government: http://politica.elpais.com/politica/2014/06/06/actualidad/1402043523_305436.html . About your numbers, Refael Shmuel counts 350000-500000 in Israel plus 200000-30000 in Europa nad America. And please, do not moan about rockets. This is not Politics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @deStrangis There are printed and online newspapers, such as [Aki Yerushalayim](http://www.aki-yerushalayim.co.il/). There is Wikipedia in [Ladino](http://lad.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Primera_Hoja). Radio Exterior de España has a weekly [show in Ladino](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/audios/emision-en-sefardi/), you can listen to past shows.

Comment: Envite: Ignorance is not a crime: The knowledge of each one of us is necessarily limited. Being proud of your ingorance, on the other hand, is less acceptable. I afraid not a single sentence in your comment is correct. 1. Ladino is a jewish dialect/language ("A language is a dialect with an army and navy" - Max Weinreich) - for this very reaosn its other name, which is preferred by most the speakers, is Judeo-Espanyol (Judeoespañol). Indeed, it was derived originally from old spanish, and it is reasonable to assume that in the past it was more similar to the Spanish dialects spoken by the gene

Comment: @user1767774 Language and dialect are very well established concepts, and only if you are trying to do demagogy you mix them. Check e.g. Ethnologue (the main internet source on languages) http://www.ethnologue.com/language/lad to see that Ladino is a language with several dialects itself. And it is classified as coming from Castilian and as a language mainly spoken (but not only) on Israel.

Comment: Very interesting. Can you provide sources (even if just wikipedia)?

Comment: @Flimzy sources for which part?

Comment: @Envite: The whole thing.

Comment: @Flimzy you can check wikipedia yourself https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_judeoespa%C3%B1ol

Comment: @Envite: On the SE network, we encourage answers to be well-referenced.  If you feel Wikipedia provides sufficient reference material for your answer, I encourage you to add that to your answer, not simply as a comment.

Comment: Ladino has evolved - no language remains static over centuries - it's just evolved in _different_ ways from Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Spanish speaker and I understand 100% of spoken Ladino. Written Ladino takes a little thought, but I can also understand it 100%.

I am Colombian and quite frankly I have a harder time understanding Caribbean dialects than I have understanding Ladino podcasts. My impression is that the division as two languages is mostly political... I think you can understand why.

But if I had to look at the two languages purely from a linguistic perspective, I'd classify them as dialects of the same language. (disclaimer: I'm not a professional linguist, just interested in the subject)

Answer (score 2):

Spanish and Ladino are indeed very closely related languages. However, there are some prominent phonetic and grammatical differences:

| Feature | Ladino | Old Spanish | Andalusian / American Spanish | Portuguese | Castilian Spanish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| retention of the [sibilants](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/why-does-latin-america-not-lisp-consonants-having-learned-its-spanish-from-sp/26692#26692) /ʃ/ and /ʒ/ (e.g. *baxo* /ʃ/, *mujer* /ʒ/) | ✅ | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |
| voicing distinction between "s/ç" and "z" (e.g. *korasón* /s/, *dezir* /z/) | ✅ | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |
| distinction between [/b/ and /v/](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25715/18348) | ✅ | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |
| word initial [latinate /f/](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/680/latin-f-to-spanish-h) (e.g. *fija, favla*) | ✅ | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |
| distinction in conjugation of [1st person plural present and preterite *-ar* verbs](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28285/18348) | ✅ | ✅ |  |  |  |
| yeísmo | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |  |
| elision of word terminal /s/ | ✅ |  | ✅ |  |  |
| word-terminal and /-k/ preceding /s/ often pronounced [ʃ] | ✅ |  |  | ✅ |  |
| word initial /nwe-/ often pronounced /mwe-/ (e.g. *muestro, muevo*) | ✅ |  |  |  |  |
| lack of *usted* | ✅ |  |  |  |  |
| variation of hebrew plural suffixes /-im/, /-ot/ (e.g. *ladrones, ladronim*) | ✅ |  |  |  |  |
| gender-marking of morphologically neutral words (e.g. *grande/granda, voz -> vozas*) | ✅ |  |  |  |  |

---

<sup>**Source:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaeo-Spanish</sup>

<sup>Some examples of Ladino speech:</sup>
<sup>- [WikiTongues: Jack Speaking Ladino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMaydZp_J30)</sup>
<sup>- [Esther Levi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q323m0RRPU)</sup>

Comment: This chart is missing several things: Old Spanish, Castilian Spanish and (EUropean) Portuguese all conjugate 2nd person plural verbs distinctly.  Similarly, (European) Portuguese distinguishes present preterite -ar verbs: *hoje nós nadamos*, *ontem nós nadámos* (cf Asturian/MIrandese *nadamos* / *nademos*)

Comment: European Portuguese in the north (and Mirandese) also distinguish the full complement of sibilants, and all Portuguese except for the extreme north/ northeast distinguish b/v

Comment: @user0721090601 thanks - I quickly changed this from a pairwise comparison without checking it was exhaustive. Can't remember what I intended by the last one (wasn't clearly phrased), so I removed it. Hope it's more accurate now!